# Using ArcGIS JavaScript API feature table using bootstrap wrappers

Tags: javascript, attribute-table, table, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, bootstrapping

I am trying to create a feature table following this sample. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/featuretable.html
This sample uses the `data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer` and `dijit/layout/ContentPane` as the containers for the map and the feature table. I however want to use the bootstrap container class as the wrapper for the map and feature table. Here's the html code for the esri sample that shows the feature table.

```
<body class="claro esri">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center', splitter:true" style="height:50%">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bot" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom', splitter:true" style="height:50%">
      <div id="myTableNode"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is my sample using bootstrap.

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
      <div class="row" style="height:50%">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="height:50%">
                    <div id="mapdiv"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="height:50%">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="height:50%">
                    <div id="featuretablediv"></div></div>  
        </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My code only works if I set the `style` for the columns and rows as above which is not ideal. Can someone explain to me why if I leave out the style, my feature table does not show up?